# Access is denied and only local connections are allowed while running Hybrid Framework in Selenium with Core Java

Tags: java, selenium, tomcat

I am new to Hybrid Framework coding, I am running simple application of navigation and also reporting result in HTML page through coding.
But I am ended up in error :

```
===============================================================================
Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\ROOT\htmlpages12-04-2016_17-00-42.html (Access is denied)
Starting ChromeDriver 2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed) on port 18650
Only local connections are allowed.
Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\ROOT\htmlpages12-04-2016_17-00-42.html (Access is denied)
=============================================================================
```

I am using Selenium 2.53.1 and Chrome Driver 2.25. Also I have installed Tomcat 8.5 before running. I update the chrome webdriver and chrome but not succeed.
Anyone can please help me in understanding the issue. Some access issue where HTML file is producing.

Answer (score 0):

**Only local connections are allowed.** This is an informational message only, telling you that the chromedriver executable will only accept connections from the local machine.  See [RemoteWebDriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/RemoteWebDriver) to learn more.

**Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\ROOT\htmlpages12-04-2016_17-00-42.html (Access is denied)**

Your current user doesn't have permissions to the tomcat folder.

In File Explorer, go to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5" folder,
right-click then select Properties->security Tab,
provide required rights to currently logged in use